# How to map application credentials to database credentials

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, credentials

As I have been led to believe, the vast majority of web apps use a single database login credential, typically hard-coded into the app code itself or a secured config file. Application logic and sessions take care of managing user interaction with the database; the database remains ignorant of who is doing what.

However, I would like to take advantage of `MySQL's current_user()` + triggers to perform certain database actions specific to the individual user.  This requires that users make database connections with their unique MySQL credentials. Because the `PASSWORD()` hashed `MySQL password` cannot be used to make connections, it is required that the app (1) stores the user's MySQL pwd in clear text in a DB table or `ACL file`, and (2) stores it in clear text in the session, to be used when making connections.  That is not ideal.

Is there a better, more secure approach for doing this?